# "Running out of temp space on your Postgres add-on" warning but can't find any evidence

Tags: postgresql, heroku

For the past week or so, I keep getting this warning daily from Heroku Postgres:

> Your database  on  is currently running out of temporary disk space.
>
> If this persists for too long, your database is at risk of crashing. In order to remediate this, we will cancel queries that use too much temporary disk space.

I have gone through the [help article linked](https://help.heroku.com/1I3XBKMT/my-heroku-postgres-instance-is-running-out-of-temporary-space) in the email for remediation steps. However, I cannot find any evidence of which queries are even writing into the temp disk space.

The `work_mem` is currently 160mb, but this has never been an issue in the past.

I am running out of ideas on how to pinpoint the cause for this warning. Any ideas?

---

Here are the steps I took so far:

- I ran the query in the link to find which queries are writing temp files via pg_stat_statements. There are 0.
- Monitored live data: I ran a query that shows active queries, and output the duration of the queries. I could not find any that ran for more than ~2 minutes.
- Found which queries in the past week are most expensive. There was only one case >3 minutes.
- Parsed through the logs and I cannot find any logs containing the text "temporary"

Comment: From here [Resource Consumption](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html) *work_mem ... Therefore, the total memory used could be many times the value of work_mem; it is necessary to keep this fact in mind when choosing the value.*.  You might want to see if the OS is swapping to disk to deal with memory consumption.  Or just lower the value and see what happens.